# How can I safely unwrap deeply nested values in a dictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, unwrap

I understand how to print the values of upper level things such as the value of "email" or the value of "name" but how would I **safely** unwrap the dictionary to print a deeper nested value such as the value of "url"?

[image]

Comment: Parse the dictionary into a proper Codable structure.

Comment: Please post the code as text and not as a photo, that way people can directly copy your code into a playground and test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting just means that the value for a particular key in your top level `[String: Any]` dictionary is another `[String: Any]` - so you just need to cast it to access nested objects.

```
// assuming you have an object `json` of `[String: Any]`
if let pictureJSON = json["picture"] as? [String: Any] {
    // if the JSON is correct, this will have a string value. If not, this will be nil
    let nestedURL = pictureJSON["url"] as? String
}
```

I feel I should mention that the process of serializing/de-serializing JSON in Swift took a big leap with Codable in Swift 4. If you have a model object you want to map this JSON to, this whole thing can be automated away (including nested objects - you just supply a nested Swift struct/class conforming to Codable). [Here's some Apple documentation on it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
if let picture = dictionary["picture"] as? [String:AnyObject] {

        if let url = picture["url"] as? String {

        }

        if let width = picture["width"] as? Int {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Swift native dictionary value type is `Any`. Most Swift types are structures. `AnyObject`  can only be used as the concrete type for  instances of classes.

Comment: I agree with that, however this example comes from a Firebase fetching method where the usage of AnyObject is recommended.